# How can I resolve 'allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates' error in flutter

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, ios9

I am getting a couple of errors related to location settings when I run my flutter app.

**Error 1:**

> /Users/mustafazaki/Downloads/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/location-3.2.4/ios/Classes/LocationPlugin.m:84:43:
> note: enclose 'allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates' in an @available check
> to silence this warning
> result(self.clLocationManager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates ? @1 :
> @0);

**Error 2:**

> /Users/mustafazaki/Downloads/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/location-3.2.4/ios/Classes/LocationPlugin.m:91:36:
> warning: 'setAllowsBackgroundLocationUpdates:' is only available on
> iOS 9.0 or newer [-Wunguarded-availability]
> self.clLocationManager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = enable;

**Error 3:**

> /Users/mustafazaki/Downloads/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/location-3.2.4/ios/Classes/LocationPlugin.m:92:36:
> note: enclose 'setShowsBackgroundLocationIndicator:' in an @available
> check to silence this warning
> self.clLocationManager.showsBackgroundLocationIndicator = enable;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to add this code to your `info.plist` at ios->Runner->Info.plist inside `<dict>` tag.

```
<key>NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string>Location permission</string>
<key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
<string>Location permission</string>
<key>NSLocationUsageDescription</key>
<string>Location permission</string>
<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string>Location permission</string>
```

stop your app, then run in terminal :

1. flutter clean
2. flutter pub get
3. flutter run